How to set up lake water pickup for sprinkler system
I live on a lake and have a sprinkler system I would like to fix. A new pump is 350, but I don’t know what setup or how to setup tubing that goes into the lake to suck the water for the pump. Any help is appreciated.

Are you 100% sure that isn't going to result in the local DNR coming down on you? Drawing water from lakes and waterways in most of the US has significant permitting requirements these days.

The pump should have instructions for the size of pipe and the max length of draw/how far it can suck water up.  You want piping or hose that does not collapse and a filter to keep out fish/weeds/wood.  Checking if permits are required plus maybe a water test for nasties not wanted on lawn/garden.

@whatisname everyone else on the lake has them and I’m just trying to upgrade it (its on gun lake in Michigan)

new pump is 350 ... is 350 the model number? ... who is the manufacturer?

As mentioned, be sure pumping from the lake is permitted.
If permitted, use the appropriate sized pipe for the pump. This is often 2 inch PVC, however we have no info on the pump.
The suction line to the pump must have a backflow check valve in the line to the pump, to keep the prime
Use a Basket strainer on the end of the intake line. Making sure it neither lays on the bottom of the lake or would get uncovered easily if the water level drops a bit.
The discharge side of the pump should have the piping going to a manifold assembly. You can buy one or make it yourself.  The advantage to having the manifold close to the pump is that there is and electric source for the controler. However it does not have to be at the pump if you have another location that is convenient and suitable.
From the manifold run your necessary supply piping and sprinkler heads where needed. Again I cannot advise on the size as additional information is needed, but these are usually 1/2 inch to 1 inch.

The pump I would get is a Wayne 1-1/2 HP Cast Iron Quick-Prime Lawn-Sprinkler Pump https://www.homedepot.com/p/Wayne-1-1-2-HP-Cast-Iron-Quick-Prime-Lawn-Sprinkler-Pump-WLS150/100017195

That pump has a 2inch intake and 1 1/2 inch discharge. It should be perfect for what you want to do.
